# Matching usermeta at registration to categories of content

Tags: categories, array, user-meta

I'm trying to connect some user_meta data from registration form to some categories set up in admin to filter the presentation on the page. This one is tripping me up because the question has multiple answers ...

Here is what I have set up so far ...

```
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

$user_values = get_user_meta( $user_id);

$interest_disaster = $user_values['interest_disaster'][0];
$interest_animals = $user_values['interest_animals'][0];
$interest_women = $user_values['interest_women'][0];
$interest_seniors = $user_values['interest_seniors'][0];
$interest_hunger_health = $user_values['interest_hunger_health'][0];
$interest_education = $user_values['interest_education'][0];
$interest_environment = $user_values['interest_environment'][0];
$interest_arts_culture = $user_values['interest_arts_culture'][0];
$interest_children_youth = $user_values['interest_children_youth'][0];
$interest_other = $user_values['interest_other'][0];
$interest_mentoring = $user_values['interest_mentoring'][0];
$interest_poverty_urban = $user_values['interest_poverty_urban'][0];
```

I can stick those in an array ...

```
$interestBlock = array(
    $interest_disaster,
    $interest_animals,
    $interest_women,
    $interest_seniors,
    $interest_hunger_health,
    $interest_education,
    $interest_environment,
    $interest_arts_culture,
    $interest_children_youth,
    $interest_other,
    $interest_mentoring,
    $interest_poverty_urban
    );
```

But I am failing badly at checking if the item exists in my category array inside a function and echoing values set in `$user_values` array out to page or sticking them in a custom query.

```
function convertInterestCategory(){

    $interestCategories = array(
    'interest_disaster',
    'interest_animals',
    'interest_women',
    'interest_seniors',
    'interest_hunger_health',
    'interest_education',
    'interest_environment',
    'interest_arts_culture',
    'interest_children_youth',
    'interest_other',
    'interest_mentoring',
    'interest_poverty_urban'
    );
$counter = 0;

//Stuff in usermeta

    foreach ($interestCategories as $counter) {
        if (in_array($interestCategories , $user_values)){
        echo $user_values[$interestCategories][0];
        $counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate help in putting together a loop function to check if item exists in `$user_values` array and is also in `$interestCategories` array, then how to return relevant results. Thanks in advance.

One by one it would look like this I guess ...

```
//Interests

if (isset($user_values['interest_disaster'][0])){
    $interest_disaster = $user_values['interest_disaster'][0];
    echo $interest_disaster;    
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_animals'][0])){
    $interest_animals = $user_values['interest_animals'][0];
    echo $interest_animals; 
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_women'][0])){
    $interest_women = $user_values['interest_women'][0];
    echo $interest_women;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_seniors'][0])){
    $interest_seniors = $user_values['interest_seniors'][0];
    echo $interest_seniors;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_hunger_health'][0])){
    $interest_hunger_health = $user_values['interest_hunger_health'][0];
    echo $interest_hunger_health;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_education'][0])){
    $interest_education = $user_values['interest_education'][0];
    echo $interest_education;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_environment'][0])){
    $interest_environment = $user_values['interest_environment'][0];
    echo $interest_environment;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_arts_culture'][0])){
    $interest_arts_culture = $user_values['interest_arts_culture'][0];
    echo $interest_arts_culture;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_children_youth'][0])){
    $interest_children_youth = $user_values['interest_children_youth'][0];
    echo $interest_children_youth;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_other'][0])){
    $interest_other = $user_values['interest_other'][0];
    echo $interest_other;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_mentoring'][0])){
    $interest_mentoring = $user_values['interest_mentoring'][0];
    echo $interest_mentoring;
}

if (isset($user_values['interest_poverty_urban'][0])){
    $interest_poverty_urban = $user_values['interest_poverty_urban'][0];
    echo $interest_poverty_urban;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
function convertInterestCategory() {

    $interest_categories = array(
        'interest_disaster',
        'interest_animals',
        'interest_women',
        'interest_seniors',
        'interest_hunger_health',
        'interest_education',
        'interest_environment',
        'interest_arts_culture',
        'interest_children_youth',
        'interest_other',
        'interest_mentoring',
        'interest_poverty_urban'
    );

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_values  = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID );

    foreach ( $interest_categories as $interest_category ) {
        if ( isset( $user_values[$interest_category][0] ) )
            echo $user_values[$interest_category][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, looks good to me, but it doesn't work and I get no errors out of wp_debug.

Comment: @Chrisdigital Check the edit.

Comment: Your update works! with a tiny bug caught by wp_debug `$user_values  = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID; );` should be `$user_values  = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID );` no semi colon after ID. Edit your entry and I will accept the answer. Thank you very much!